# Estructuras en C, diferencia de tiempo del 40% sin saber por qué

Tags: c, time, struct

Estoy queriendo acceder a grafos ya dados. Tengo miles de líneas de código. Pongo algunos ejemplos del antes y del después.

```c
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef struct GrafoSt *Grafo;
typedef struct DuplaSt *Dupla;

struct GrafoSt
{
    ...
    Dupla colorVer;

    ...
};

struct DuplaSt
{
    u32 v1;
    u32 v2;
};

// Ejemplo: 

Grafo ConstruccionGrafo() {

    g->colorVer = malloc(n*sizeof(struct DuplaSt));
    ...
    g->colorVer[0].v2 = 0;
    u32 posVer = 0;
    for(u32 i = 1; i < 2*n; i++)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            posVer++;
            g->colorVer[posVer].v2 = posVer;
        }
        else
            ...
    }

}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es **sacar la estructura "DuplaSt".**

Lo que pensé fue:

```c
struct GrafoSt
{
    ...
    u32** colorVer;

    ...
};

// Ejemplo

Grafo ConstruccionGrafo() {
    for(u32 i = 0; i < n; i++)
        g->colorVer[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(unsigned int));

    g->colorVer[0][1] = 0;
    u32 posVer = 0;
    for(u32 i = 1; i < 2*n; i++)
    {
        if (...)
        {
            posVer++;
            g->colorVer[posVer][1] = posVer;
        }
        else
            ...

    }
```

Y listo.

O sea, tengo grafos muy grandes, y con la primera opción cargar el grado, correr el algoritmo de greedy muchas veces con distintos reordenamientos, etc, etc, tarda mucho menos que con la segunda técnica.

No sabría decir por qué. Porque me parece que son acciones casi muy similares pero una diferencia de optimización muy elevada.

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir en la pregunta el código que has utilizado antes y después del cambio de la estructura de datos?

Comment: @ordago ahi lo mejore un poco. Tengo muchas lineas. Pero así seria un ejemplo para acceder.

Comment: A ver si me aclaro: ¿ Estás preguntando el porqué 2 códigos distintos hacen cosas distintas ? O_O

Comment: Pensaría que el hecho de utilizar el malloc para buscar memoria disponible incrementa el tiempo de ejecución. Además con la primera opcion, al tener una estructura definida (tamaño y offsets), creo que el compilador podría optimizar las instrucciones para acceder a los datos. En cambio con el malloc, las direcciones son variables en tiempo de ejecución, dependiendo de la memora asignada.

Comment: Hacen dos cosas iguales. Pero en tiempo es muchísima la diferencia. El primero es mucho mas eficiente que el segundo. Y bueno, ver si se puede sacar esa DuplaSt por otra cosa, no por la que hice yo porque es muy lento.

Comment: @gustavovelascoh.. tiene mucho sentido lo que decís.. es verdad. Se te ocurriría alguna otra forma de sacar esa estructura DuplaSt? O casi que ni hay muchas mas opciones?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "sacar"?

Comment: Quiero ver si hay alguna otra forma de quitar/eliminar la estructura "DuplaSt" y que colorVer siga funcionando con mas o menos la misma eficiencia que antes. Yo lo intente y claramente esa idea no era la correcta. Habra alguna otra forma o esa que ya esta es  la mejor?

Comment: ¿Por qué en el primer ejemplo no hace falta `malloc()`? tal como yo lo veo `colorVer` en el primer ejemplo es de tipo `Dupla`, es decir, puntero a `DuplaSt`. Como tal puntero debe ser inicializado y no veo dónde. Cuando luego usas `g->colorVer[0]` ¿a dónde irá? Para lo que no requiere malloc() es para el valor de cada `colorVer[i]`, eso sí. Pero tampoco lo necesitarías en el segundo ejemplo si el puntero en vez de ser a puntero lo haces a array de dos `u32`.

Comment: Y si defines `ColorVer` como `u32 ColorVer[2];` dentro de la estructura `GrafoSt`?

Comment: lo voy a intentar así y a ver como funciona.. Muchas gracia!!!

Comment: @abulafia perdon, no lo habia puesto en el código ahi lo puse.. si tiene que haber malloc, cuando estaba copiando código me lo saltee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O sea, tengo grafos muy grandes, y con la primera opción cargar el grado, correr el algoritmo de greedy muchas veces con distintos reordenamientos, etc, etc, tarda mucho menos que con la segunda técnica.

La reserva de memoria dinámica es un proceso pesado. En cada petición, el Sistema Operativo tiene que localizar una porción de memoria que no esté ya reservada... si no encuentra ningún bloque dentro de la memoria de la aplicación, entonces tiene que reservar un nuevo bloque para dicha aplicación y asignar memoria de ese bloque... Es un proceso que consume su tiempo.

Dicho esto, en el primer caso tenemos **una única reserva de memoria**:

```
g->colorVer = malloc(n*sizeof(struct DuplaSt));
```

Mientras que en el segundo, tenemos `n`:

```
for(u32 i = 0; i < n; i++)
    g->colorVer[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Luego parece obvio pensar que el segundo algoritmo será más lento que el primero.